# Utilizing the full power of my workstation

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, cpu-speed, performance-tuning

I am not a gamer. Used to be, 10+ years ago. My workstation is strictly for business:

- Quickbooks
- Excel
- Access
- General Business

QuickBooks is tied to a synchronization engine that is synchronizing, at times, 100,000+ items with our web database (a true monster of awesome power) at any given time. We recently ran into a ceiling with the sync engine that was causing QB to choke, giving memory errors and so on, even with 32 gigs of RAM and an Intel 3960x processor.

So, naturally, I went out and replaced the drives with all SSDs (Samsung EVO - latest version - 250 gigs per drive). Windows (7 Professional - Licensed, not hacked, important updates only have been installed) runs on one... apps on another... storage on another. Upgraded the RAM of better quality running at 1866, 64 gigs of it. Popped in a video card of far greater power (GTX 660). Re-wired our entire household to hard-wired Internet on powerful business-class gigabit Cisco router and gigabit switches. This is all operating on a Sabertooth X79 motherboard with latest BIOS, et al. Even set a safe overclock on the CPU to 4.7ghz, attached to a Corsair H100 liquid cooling system.

Essentially, the intention was to eliminate any and all bottlenecks that would prevent us from taking FULL advantage of the true power of this workstation. Now, with high hopes of an SQL UPDATE query running five or ten times faster. Even got a pro version of Process Lasso and applied the highest level priority to all associated processes... Intuit DB manager, Quickbooks & associated processes, SQL server, sync manager... all running at the highest CPU priority, highest I/O, and maximum power level made available to them.

Unfortunately, while things ARE running faster, and not crashing or choking, it's still not even close to what I would have expected. Taking a closer look at the CPU core usage and RAM usage, Windows is BARELY using the RAM and only using about 10-15% of the CPU. Of course it's caching most of the RAM. Overall, I'd say that Windows is only properly utilizing about 10% of the true raw power of this new setup.

What other sort of tweaks can I make to my system that will FORCE Windows to stop treating this hardware setup like a lamb, and start treating it like a rhinoceros, which is exactly what it is. I did read somewhere that Windows will only allow a program to use a maximum of 2-4 gigs of RAM, and only a certain % of the processor... hoping there is some way to push the envelope without frying the machine.

Lastly, yes, I realize this is a major newbie question but hoping there is a way upward from here.

[image]

Comment: So QuickBooks, being a 32-bit process, is holding everything down? I knew there was a reason people were willing to pay a quarter of a million dollars for something else, which functionally accomplishes the same thing (but faster). No ideas for a workaround? No hacks? Tricks? Nothing?

Comment: Office 2013 64-Bit confirmed. I connect to the Quickbooks DB via QODBC driver and it does require a 64-bit data source which has been properly configured. EDIT: And yes, I am willing to admit that I likely did not understand the original bottleneck. Thankfully, we got past the crashing but still, I feel like this thing is Godzilla in chains right now.

Comment: Give me about ten minutes and I will provide.

Comment: [RAMMAP](https://s3.amazonaws.com/stack_img/RAMMAP-2014-05-20.png) - EDIT: Just a note, this is not a HIGH stress situation, but a fairly normal one. This is about the level of strain that this workstation will be under in most circumstances.

Comment: Just realized I failed to answer your other question. No, I have the paging file turned off. No "out of virtual memory" errors happening here. Would I see a significant performance enhancement by utilizing SSD caching? EDIT: I do have Skype, if you want to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14638/discussion-between-furrywombat-and-ramhound).

Comment: The chat basically contains everything I was able to come up with to help this user.  Without more specific information which I didn't want to ask for there really isn't an exact answer.  It sounds like the system configuration is sound ( page file is disabled ) this indicate all virtual memory is handled on the fly with physical memory.  I indicate a RAMDisk might even further increase I/O performance.  However, it seems like the lack of system utilization is the engine used to process the transactions itself.  I removed previous comments so this single comment could be stand in their place.